# Splitting a string and retaining the delimiter with the delimiter appearing contiguously

Tags: python, string

I have the following string:

```
bar = 'F9B2Z1F8B30Z4'
```

I have a function `foo` that splits the string on `F`, then adds back the `F` delimiter.

```
def foo(my_str):
    res = ['F' + elem for elem in my_str.split('F') if elem != '']
    return res
```

This works ***unless*** there are two "F"s back-to-back in the string.  For example,

```
foo('FF9B2Z1F8B30Z4')
```

returns

```
['F9B2Z1', 'F8B30Z4']
```

(the double "F" at the start of the string is not processed)

I'd like the function to split on the first "F" and add it to the list, as follows:

```
['F', 'F9B2Z1', 'F8B30Z4']
```

If there is a double "F" in the middle of the string, then the desired behavior would be:

```
foo('F9B2Z1FF8B30Z4')

['F9B2Z1', 'F', 'F8B30Z4']
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `if elem != ''` eliminates the first F.

Comment: What if the string doesn't begin with `F`, e.g. `abcF123`?

Comment: Assuming the strings don't deviate from this you could also use `re.findall(r'F[^F]*', input_str)`

Comment: @Barmar -- if the string begins with something other than `F`, the function would still need to prepend an `F` to that value (e.g. `['Fabc', 'F123']`

Comment: All you have to do is remove the `if` clause from the list comprehension.

Comment: @MYousefi -- removing the `if` clause is not an option because doing so would add an extra `F` in this case:  `F9B2Z1F8B30Z4` ==> `['F', 'F9B2Z1', 'F8B30Z4']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the filtering `if`, use slicing instead because an empty string is a problem only at the beginning:

```
def foo(my_str):
    res = ['F' + elem for elem in my_str.split('F')]
    return res[1:] if my_str and my_str[0]=='F' else res
```

Output:

```
>>> foo('FF9B2Z1F8B30Z4')
['F', 'F9B2Z1', 'F8B30Z4']

>>> foo('FF9B2Z1FF8B30Z4FF')
['F', 'F9B2Z1', 'F', 'F8B30Z4', 'F', 'F']

>>> foo('9B2Z1F8B30Z4')
['F9B2Z1', 'F8B30Z4']

>>> foo('')
['F']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex it can be done with

```
import re

pattern = r'^[^F]+|(?<=F)[^F]*'
```

The `^[^F]+` captures all characters at the beginning of strings that do not start with `F`.

`(?<=F)[^F]*` captures anything following an `F` so long as it is not an `F` character including empty matches.

```
>>> print(['F' + x for x in re.findall(pattern, 'abcFFFAFF')])
['Fabc', 'F', 'F', 'FA', 'F', 'F']

>>> print(['F' + x for x in re.findall(pattern, 'FFabcFA')])
['F', 'Fabc', 'FA']

>>> print(['F' + x for x in re.findall(pattern, 'abc')])
['Fabc']
```

Note that this returns nothing for empty strings. If empty strings need to return `['F']` then pattern can be changed to `pattern = r'^[^F]+|(?<=F)[^F]*|^$'` adding `^$` to capture empty strings.